# Problems with a virtual column

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm using a virtual column to concatenate the first and middle name of employees. The virtual column is declared like this:

```
"NOMBRECOMPLETO" VARCHAR2(201 BYTE) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("MIEMBRONOMBRE"||' '||"MIEMBROAPELLIDO") VIRTUAL.
```

If I make a simple select over my table everyting is fine, it works. But when I start making joins with other tables and applying filters, sometimes the value of the virtual column returns blank.
Sometimes it's just one filter that makes it disappear.

Has this ever happened to anyone? Im using Oracle 12c

Comment: Sounds like a possible Oracle bug.  Try issuing this statement before you run your query: `alter session set "_replace_virtual_columns"=false`.  This is _not_ a solution, just a diagnostic.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the outputs

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT  C.NOMBRECOMPLETO NOMBRECOMPLETO,
         round(a.valor,2) VALOR, b.nombre FROM TBL1 C
          JOIN TBL2 A ON A.member= C.member
          RIGHT JOIN TBL3 B
          ON A.TR= B.TR
          WHERE CVEPLANILLA = :PAR1
          ORDER BY C.MIEMBROCARNE,DECODE(A.cvetransaccion, :PAR3, 1, :PAR4 ,9999999999999,2)
          )
          PIVOT (SUM(VALOR) for NOMBRE IN (:STRING))

So, the column "nombrecompleto is a virtual column, depending on what parameters I use, it shows the value or it goes blank. (Im using plsql to execute, a function returning a cursor)